# Recreating Postgres COPY directly in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a block of data, currently as a list of n-tuples but the format is pretty flexible, that I'd like to append to a Postgres table - in this case, each n-tuple corresponds to a row in the DB.

What I had been doing up to this point is writing these all to a CSV file and then using postgres' COPY to bulk load all of this into the database.  This works, but is suboptimal, I'd prefer to be able to do this all directly from python.  Is there a method from within python to replicate the COPY type bulk load in Postgres?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you're using the psycopg2 driver, the cursors provide a `copy_to` and `copy_from` function that can read from any file-like object (including a `StringIO` buffer).

There are examples in the files [examples/copy_from.py](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/examples/copy_from.py) and [examples/copy_to.py](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/examples/copy_to.py) that come with the [psycopg2 source distribution](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2).

This excerpt is from the `copy_from.py` example:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE test_copy (fld1 text, fld2 text, fld3 int4)")

# anything can be used as a file if it has .read() and .readline() methods
data = StringIO.StringIO()
data.write('\n'.join(['Tom\tJenkins\t37',
                  'Madonna\t\N\t45',
                  'Federico\tDi Gregorio\t\N']))
data.seek(0)

curs.copy_from(data, 'test_copy')
```

Comment: My pleasure... if it works for you, don't forget to hit the accept button for this answer. I've noticed that you haven't accepted any of the answers to your other questions, but the "accept" checkmark helps others who have the same problem know at a glance which answer solved the problem for you.

Comment: Please modify this to include booleans and arrays as these seems to not work for me!