# Remote CSV import Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, raspberry-pi

What is the best way to automatically import CSVs into a remote Postgres server?

I am using a temperature sensor connected to my raspberry Pi to log data (using a python script) into a CSV file:

```
2013-11-11 23:00:25,27.187
2013-11-11 23:00:31,27.25
2013-11-11 23:00:36,27.25
2013-11-11 23:00:41,27.5
```

Using the COPY command in psql, I have no problems importing into a table if the CSV file is on the machine running postgres.

How can I import the data directly into a table on my postgres server from my Raspberry Pi?

(In the future, I would like to have my Pi import data autonomously, updating the current table by adding new rows as the Pi logs more data)

Comment: The simplest thing would be to have a script that first scp's the file from the Pi and then runs psql -c "Copy .."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recreating Postgres COPY directly in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869973/recreating-postgres-copy-directly-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have network connectivity, you should be able to make a socket connection to PostgreSQL and insert rows into a table as sensor data is collected.

The Connection Settings will need to have listen_addresses set up so that remote clients can connect with it.

Comment: Thank everyone you this worked perfectly for me. After I made a connection used the \copy command mentioned by @peter.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the `COPY` command works with a file residing on the database server host.  Instead, you should use the `\copy` command in psql, which reads the file from the client host.  See the man page of psql for details.