# Copy (from) csv with heades in postgres with python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to fill a table from CSV files in a python script.

The SQL statement, which follows, runs without error:

```
COPY registro
FROM '/home/pablo/Escritorio/puntos/20140227.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV header;
```

CSV has headers, and using `header` parameter, it imports without error.

The problem comes when I execute it from my python script. The only way I've found not to try to import the headers is with `copy_expert()` method. I get no error message but the table is still empty after I run the Python script below.

Any possible clue? Or maybe any other way to copy a table from CSV with headers?

Thanks.

```
#/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psycopg2
import os
import glob
DSN = "dbname=gps user=postgres host=localhost"
con = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
cur = con.cursor()
my_file = open('/home/pablo/Escritorio/puntos/20140227.csv')
#This is only a test file, not all the directory
sql = "COPY registro FROM stdin DELIMITER \',\' CSV header;"
cur.copy_expert(sql, my_file)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recreating Postgres COPY directly in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869973/recreating-postgres-copy-directly-in-python)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, it not talks about copy_expert() neither CSV headers

Comment: It was more like a "That might also work" forgot to write this as a comment.

Answer (score 20):

I'd try `con.commit()` after `cur.copy_expert()`.

Also I would avoid preprocessing and uploading the file row by row as Sam P. pointed out above if the dataset is large. `cur.copy_expert()` is significantly faster.

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/database')
cur = conn.cursor()
copy_sql = """
           COPY table_name FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
           DELIMITER as ','
           """
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: should you not also close the connection?

Comment: Does the copy_from(file, table_name, feature=value) method have an option for header=true?

Comment: @aydow, closing the connection is not a bad idea. I should've included that in my original post outside of the with block

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend dealing with the csv file in python first. It will be best to structure the data pulled from the csv file into rows/columns (in python this will nested lists, or a list of a tuples) then you can construct & execute SQL commands based on that data iteratively.

Use the `csv` library to interact with the csv file, take a look at the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. It's very user friendly and will help you with a lot of your problems.

Here's a way to do it without `csv` (as I can't remember all the functions off the top of my head), however it would be best not to use this approach:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psycopg2
import os
import glob
DSN = "dbname=gps user=postgres host=localhost"
con = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
cur = con.cursor()

# 'rb' used as I don't know the encoding of your file
# just use r if it's in utf-8 or a known/consistent charset
with open(file,'rb') as open_file:
    my_file = open_file.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')

data = my_file.splitlines()
data = [r.split(delimiter) for r in data]

data = data[1:] # get rid of headers

for r in data:
     # create command
     # cur.execute(command)
```

Comment: This line helps me while reading data from csv/json and copy into flex in vertica. Thanks -:)      
my_file = open_file.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')

Comment: check this for detail.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710664/copying-data-to-vertica-using-python/38994233#38994233