# Copying data to Vertica using python

Tags: python, vertica

I use `python` and `vertica-python` library to `COPY` data to `Vertica` DB

```
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
vsql_cur = connection.cursor()

with open("/tmp/vertica-test-insert", "rb") as fs:
    vsql_cur.copy( "COPY table FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' ", fs, buffer_size=65536)
    connection.commit()
```

It inserts data, but only 5 rows, although the file contains more. Could this be related to db settings or it's some client issue?

Comment: Where is your debugging code? Did you check rejected rows?

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me:

## For JSON

```
# for json file
with open("D:/SampleCSVFile_2kb/tweets.json", "rb") as fs:
    my_file = fs.read().decode('utf-8')
    cur.copy( "COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN parser fjsonparser()", my_file)
    connection.commit()
```

## For CSV

```
# for csv file
with open("D:/SampleCSVFile_2kb/SampleCSVFile_2kb.csv", "rb") as fs:
    my_file = fs.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')
    cur.copy( "COPY STG.unstruc_data FROM STDIN PARSER FDELIMITEDPARSER (delimiter=',', header='false') ", my_file) # buffer_size=65536
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Very likely that you have rows getting rejected. Assuming you are using 7.x, you can add:

[`[ REJECTED DATA {'path' [ ON nodename ]  [, ...] | AS TABLE 'reject_table'} ]`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm)

You can also query this after the copy execution to see the summary of results:

`SELECT`[`GET_NUM_ACCEPTED_ROWS()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/GET_NUM_ACCEPTED_ROWS.htm)`,`[`GET_NUM_REJECTED_ROWS()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/GET_NUM_REJECTED_ROWS.htm)`;`