# Internal Error on trying copy data to postgres table from python code using copy_from function of psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I did this in my python code, based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/examples/copy_from.py) and it's mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869973/recreating-postgres-copy-directly-in-python)

```
# anything can be used as a file if it has .read() and .readline() methods
data = StringIO.StringIO()
data.write('\n'.join(['Tom\tJenkins\t37',
                  'Madonna\t\N\t45',
                  'Federico\tDi Gregorio\t\N']))
data.seek(0)

curs.copy_from(data, 'distributors')
```

I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    cursor.copy_from(data, 'distributors')
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html):

There was an attempted query run of an erroneous query using the same database connection. (For details: I had run a copy_from execution on this db connection with incorrect data. It had failed. And, then I modified my data to be in correct format)

When your previous query/command on the database using this connection had a problem/error, it needs to be rolled back using **`connection.rollback()`** call. Once, you execute that code, and re-run the fresh correct code, you would get data to be properly copied from Python code to Postgres database.

Comment: I did a con.commit() after each statement and worked like a charm.