# Using Postgres's COPY FROM file query in Python without writing to a temporary file

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I need to load data from some source data sources to a Postgres database.
To do this task, I first write the data to a temporary CSV file and then load data from the CSV file to Postgres database using COPY FROM query. I do all of this on Python.

The code looks like this:

```
table_name = 'products'
temp_file = "'C:\\Users\\username\\tempfile.csv'"
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host, port, user, password, database)
cursor = db_conn.cursor()
query = """COPY """ + table_name + """ FROM """ + temp_file + " WITH NULL AS ''; """
cursor.execute(query)
```

I want to avoid the step of writing to the intermediate file. Instead, I would like to write to a Python object and then load data to postgres database using COPY FROM file method.

I am aware of [this technique of using psycopg2's copy_from method which copies data from a StringIO object to the postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869973/recreating-postgres-copy-directly-in-python). However, I cannot use psycopg2 for a reason and hence, I don't want my COPY FROM task to be dependent on a library. I want it to be Postgres query which can be run by any other postgres driver as well.

Please advise a better way of doing this without writing to an intermediate file.

Comment: "However, I cannot use psycopg2 for a reason". And the reason is...?

Comment: The package is banned for use in my job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could call the *psql* command-line tool from your script (i.e. using `subprocess.call`) and leverage its `\copy` command, piping the output of one instance to the input of another, avoiding a temp file. i.e.

`psql -X -h from_host -U user -c "\copy from_table to stdout" | psql -X -h to_host -U user -c "\copy to_table from stdin"`

This assumes the table exists in the destination database. If not, a separate command would first need to create it.

Also, note that one caveat of this method is that errors from the first `psql` call can get swallowed by the piping process.

Comment: My system requires db password to execute sql,how can i give it in copy command

Comment: @kaviya.P: The simplest way to accomplish that, especially when using psql in a piped form like above, would be to setup a pgpass file on the box so you don't get prompted for a password. See more info here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 7):

`psycopg2` has integrated support for the `COPY` wire-protocol, allowing you to use `COPY ... FROM STDIN` / `COPY ... TO STDOUT`.

See [Using `COPY TO` and `COPY FROM`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) in the `psycopg2` docs.

Since you say you can't use psycopg2, you're out of luck. Drivers must understand `COPY TO STDOUT` / `COPY FROM STDIN` in order to use them, or must provide a way to write raw data to the socket so you can hijack the driver's network socket and implement the `COPY` protocol yourself. Driver specific code is absolutely required for this, it is not possible to simply use the DB-API.

So khampson's suggestion, while usually a really bad idea, seems to be your only alternative.

(I'm posting this mostly to make sure that other people who find this answer who *don't* have restrictions against using `psycopg2` do the sane thing.)

If you *must* use `psql`, please:

- [Use the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) with the `Popen` constructor
- Pass `-qAtX` and `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` to `psql` to get sane behaviour for batching.
- Use the array form command, e.g. `['psql', '-v', 'ON_ERROR_STOP=1', '-qAtX', '-c', '\copy mytable from stdin']`, rather than using a shell.
- Write to `psql`'s stdin, then close it, and wait for `psql` to finish.
- Remember to trap exceptions thrown on command failure. Let `subprocess` capture stderr and wrap it in the exception object.

It's safer, cleaner, and easier to get right than the old-style `os.popen2` etc.

Comment: I keep getting this error unfortunately when i try your solution: 'could not find a "psql" to execute\r\npsql: could not create socket: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.\r\r\n (0x0000277A/10106)\r\n '

Comment: If i try the rendered command string direct in a cmd box however, it works great.

Comment: @ParisChar I have no idea what weird proxy or tool you're using. Post a new question with details.

Comment: @ParisChar I had the same error message and for me it was a broken env. If you pass an `env` to `subprocess.run`, this will be used *instead* of the existing env, not in addition to it. So use `os.environ` and extend it with your other variables, then pass that to `subprocess.run`. Maybe this helps you and others who end up here.