# Using COPY instead of INSERT within python for postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a python script that adds many entries to a Postgres table using `INSERT`. I want to use `COPY` instead for speed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869973/recreating-postgres-copy-directly-in-python) gets halfway there, but does not instruct how to format lists, booleans, etc.

With `INSERT`, `psycopg2` handles formatting for you:

```
foo = [0,1,2]
bar = '"Hello," she said'
cur.execute("insert into table (foo, bar) values (%s, %s)", (foo, bar))
```

However, this doesn't work with copy, as you have to use csv formatted data:

```
foo = [0,1,2]
bar = '"Hello," she said'
csv_string = "\t".join(str(foo), str(bar))
buf = io.StringIO()
buf.write(csv_string)
buf.seek(0)
cur.copy_from(buf, 'table')
# Does not work, as data is not formatted properly
```

Formatting with csv writer doesn't work either:

```
writer = csv.writer(buf)
csv_writer.writerow([foo,bar])
buf.seek(0)
cur.copy_from(buf, 'table')
# Fails on lists which get formatted as [], fails on NULL values
```

How do I format my data into Postgres-compatible CSV strings? I tried `cur.mogrify`, but it formats lists as `ARRAY[0,1,2]` instead of `{0,1,2}`, and `copy_from` expects the latter.

I suppose I could try to roll my own string formatter, but surely there is a better way?

Comment: you don't format data for copy as it originally copies csv

Comment: Do not use `copy`. Use [`execute_values`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) in instead.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: the whole point is that I want to use COPY for speed improvement. Using insert and execute_values is slow.

Comment: The whole point of `execute_values` is that it is much faster then `insert`.

Comment: If using csv, you have to use `copy_expert()` so that you can pass the required format argument(s). Search a bit, lots of examples.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: `execute_values` still uses `insert`. I suppose you mean that it's faster to insert many values at once with `execute_values` rather than one at a time with `execute`, which is true. However `copy` is still 6.5x faster according to this benchmark: https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/efa9a69926a754bebf0e9078fd085df6

Comment: @IljaEverilä I am aware of `copy_expert.` The problem is how to format the CSV data in the first place. I have done lots of searching but could not find any examples of how to turn python data types into Postgres-compatible CSV. (Formatting arrays, null types, etc. properly.) If you have found any, please post a link!

Comment: Missed the real point of your post, sorry. The use of the term Comma Separated Values threw me off, since you explicitly have to tell COPY to parse such (compared to the tab separated default format, the usage of which I also missed in your code).

Answer (score 1):

The following example works:

```
foo = [0,1,2]
bar = '"Hello," she said'
csv_string = str(foo)+"\t"+ str(bar)
print(csv_string)
buf = io.StringIO()
buf.write(csv_string)
buf.seek(0)
cur.copy_from(buf, 'table')
```

The difference between your code and the code above is line #3 (csv_string=...).

Anyway, I'm recommending using copy_expert instead of copy_from. This is more flexible option.